Trying to pick images using Uri but getting endless Security Exceptions
Hey Im making simple simple activity that has the whole purpose opening the gallery, making the user choose a picture and taking that picture's uri value, saving on sharedpref but also making it the background image of the said activity. From what I've read online this has been quite controversial issue ever since last year and the solutions, suggestions just fell short for the current security necessities. So, how do I pull the image then? What should I change in my code?
public class SetBackgroundsAct extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String SHARED_PREF_BACK = "imageURI";
    private static final String KEY_SHARED_PREF_BACK = "imageURI";
    private Button changeBackground;
    private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Uri imageUri;
    private String path;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_backgrounds);
        LoadSharePrefs();
        changeBackground = findViewById(R.id.setBackgroundButton);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.backgroundImageview);
        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);


        changeBackground.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                gallery.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(gallery, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });

        };

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            imageUri = data.getData();
            imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_BACK,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor =sharedPreferences.edit();
            path = imageUri.toString();
            editor.putString(KEY_SHARED_PREF_BACK, path);
            editor.apply();

        }
    }

    private void LoadSharePrefs()
    {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_BACK,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String imagePath = sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_SHARED_PREF_BACK, "");
        if (!imagePath.isEmpty()) {
            imageUri = Uri.parse(imagePath);

        }
    }

}

Also on the Manifest file I think Im asking the current permissions but Im not sure anymore so posting the related ones here as well
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"
        tools:ignore="SelectedPhotoAccess" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

So I found the solution:
Basically you need to ask the right permissions in order to access the gallery. First add this variable:
```private static final int REQUEST_READ_STORAGE_PERMISSION = 2;```

then you have to ask the permissin right under onCreate which is this:
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please allow image access to edit backgrounds.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES}, REQUEST_READ_STORAGE_PERMISSION);
        }

Now when loading the image and recieving it's URI value you need to use ContentResolver. Which you gotta write this code in onActivityResult:
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
            contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(imageUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            getContentResolver().getPersistedUriPermissions();

imageUri is a variable I added myself like this:
private Uri imageUri;
Extra tip, if you're saving it to Sharedpreferences like me, turn it into a String and save it like that (instead of saving it's path):
editor.putString(KEY_SHARED_PREF_BACK, imageUri.toString());
May this help someone, I know noone did to me. Good luck.
